# procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name

Tags: events, vb6, toolbar

I am just novice and I tried to make a simple program in Visual Basic 6. The code is almost equivalent to that in the textbook. It was meant to be a kind of a paint program. Surprisingly, it couldn't be compiled with the error given in the title of this question.
This is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim Col As Long

Private Sub Form_Load()
    AutoRedraw = True
    BackColor = vbWhite
    Col = vbBlack
    DrawWidth = 3
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    CommonDialog1.ShowOpen
    Form1.Picture = LoadPicture(CommonDialog1.FileName)
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
    CommonDialog1.ShowSave
    SavePicture Image, CommonDialog1.FileName
End Sub

Private Sub Command3_Click()
    CommonDialog1.ShowColor
    Col = CommonDialog1.Color
End Sub

Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    PSet (X, Y), Col
End Sub

Private Sub Toolbar1_ButtonClick(ByVal Button As MSComctlLib.Button)
    Select Case Button.Key
    Case "Line1"
        DrawWidth = 3
    Case "Line2"
        DrawWidth = 20
    End Select
End Sub
```

The application crashes on the following line:

```
Private Sub Toolbar1_ButtonClick(ByVal Button As MSComctlLib.Button)
```

With the error:

> procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure
>   having the same name

Answer (score 22):

The problem is here:

```
Private Sub Toolbar1_ButtonClick(ByVal Button As MSComctlLib.Button)
```

Ok, since you are coding in VB6, you get to learn some of the tricks in the VB6 playbook.  Temporarily rename the method to something else like qqToolbar_ButtonClick, then go to the designer and click the button in the toolbar to regenerate the event in the code.

In the event that the signature has been mistyped, it will regenerate from the designer correctly and you might see the issue.

Another check is to see if the ToolBar1 was added to a control array?  In that case, the method signature needs to look like this:

```
Private Sub Toolbar1_ButtonClick(ByVal Index as Integer, ByVal Button As MSComctlLib.Button)
```

I hope one of these helps solve the issue for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for so quick answer!!! The first your advice helped me to overcome this problem!