# VBA class module not properly implementing Interface variant property

Tags: excel, vba, oop, interface, variant

I am trying to implement an interface that represents an abstraction of Tables in my VBA project, so that I can pass an array of the interface type into a function and display all tables, regardless of which subtype the table is. I am declaring some properties in the interface that all tables will have, but when trying to use an array as a interface member, I am getting the following error:
[Implementation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AoHW.png)

When I comment out both of the variant type members in the interface, the testing works fine.

```
Client
Got here
Scenario: test
Got there
(Client) got here
```

Here is my interface:

```
'Class name: IFScenarioTable
'Interface that generalizes all types of tables

' ----- INTERFACE MEMBERS ------
Public Scenario As String
Public ScenarioDetailsArray As Variant 'Array
Public TableLength As Integer
Public Result As ScenarioResult 'Custom class
'Public Tariffs As Variant 'Array


' ----- INTERFACE METHOD STUBS -----
Public Sub PrintInfo()
```

Here is one of the Classes that implements the interface:

```
Option Explicit
'Class name: PVScenarioTable
Implements IFST

'Variables for IFScenarioTable implementation
Private m_scenario As String
Private m_scenarioDetailsArray As Variant
Private m_tableLength As Integer
Private m_result As ScenarioResult
Private m_tariffs As Variant
'-----------------------------------------------------------------
'Implement IFScenarioTable variables

'scenario GET/SET
Property Let IFST_Scenario(ByVal Scenario As String)
    m_scenario = Scenario
End Property
Property Get IFST_Scenario() As String
    IFST_Scenario = m_scenario
End Property

'scenarioDetailsArray GET/SET
Property Let IFST_ScenarioDetailsArray(ByVal pScenarioDetailsArray As Variant)
    Set m_scenarioDetailsArray = pScenarioDetailsArray
End Property
Property Get IFST_ScenarioDetailsArray() As Variant
    IFST_ScenarioDetailsArray = m_scenarioDetailsArray
End Property

'tableLength GET/SET
Property Let IFST_TableLength(ByVal TableLength As Integer)
    m_tableLength = TableLength
End Property
Property Get IFST_TableLength() As Integer
    IFST_TableLength = m_tableLength
End Property

'result GET/SET
Property Set IFST_Result(ByVal Result As ScenarioResult)
    m_result = Result
End Property
Property Get IFST_Result() As ScenarioResult
    IFST_Result = m_result
End Property

'tariffs GET/SET
Property Let IFST_tariffs(ByVal Tariffs As Variant)
    Set m_tariffs = Tariffs
End Property
Property Get IFST_tariffs()
    IFST_tariffs = m_tariffs
End Property
'-----------------------------------------------------------------

'-----------------------------------------------------------------

'Implement methods
Public Sub Test()
    Debug.Print "test"
End Sub
'PrintInfo implementation
Public Sub IFST_PrintInfo()
    Debug.Print "Got here"
    Debug.Print "Scenario: " & m_scenario
    Debug.Print "Got there"
End Sub
```

And here is the client that tests the interface/class code:

```
Public Sub Client()
    Dim PVTable As PVScenarioTable
    Set PVTable = New PVScenarioTable
    With PVTable
        .IFST_Scenario = "test"
        .IFST_PrintInfo
    End With
    Debug.Print "(Client) got here"
End Sub
```

Comment: is this right ?  parametre is given byVal but you are going to set the modul variable ?



`Property Let IFST_ScenarioDetailsArray(ByVal pScenarioDetailsArray As Variant)
    Set m_scenarioDetailsArray = pScenarioDetailsArray
End Property`

Comment: @MaMe I am not sure if this is the right syntax, I am pretty new to vba. Here I am trying to create a setter method, so whatever you pass into the function here will update the module's m_scenarioDetailsArray member. If there is something wrong please let me know how i can fix it

Comment: It looks like for the Variant interface members, you will need to implement Get, Let, and Set.  You can see this in the IDE if you select IFST in the left dropdown and then look at the contents of the right dropdown.  You likely have some items that are not in **bold**.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thank you!!! This did the trick. Also, some helpful tips regarding method declarations I found here to supplement Brian's comment - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12608758/18174191

Comment: IFST is not the name of your interface. In VBA an interface should contain only method stubs and enumerations used by the implementing classes.